# How do I know which video API I'm using?

Tags: drivers, video, ffmpeg

I'm looking into ffmpeg hardware suport for different video APIs:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Intel i7 7th gen. How do I know which of these video APIs I use?

Comment: I doubt you can use any of those APIs. An Intel GPU, however, is another story, and as the table indicates, it has access to VAAPI and OPENCL. You can run `vainfo` to verify.